# CSS Animations : multiple animations chained to 1 class

Tags: css, animation, css-transitions

people I'm hoping someone can give me some help. I've been a stackflow reader for a long time learned many things from helpful people. Hopefully if this question gets answered it will also help lots of other people as well.

I would like only simple easy solutions, I've seen how crazy and complex people keep replying to posts making it even harder. Simple and working would be fine.

Here's the CSS3 animation code now "bounce" works, and "tada" works 
but only if you assign 1 or the other to the element but I cannot get it to chain using both "bounce & tada" once I see how you tie these together i can then hopefully chain even more. But for now 2 will be fine as a learning stepping stone.

```
.bounce {
  animation-name: tada, bounce;
  transform-origin: center bottom;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  }
  @keyframes bounce {
  0%, 20%, 53%, 80%, 100% {
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  }
  40%, 43% {
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.755, 0.050, 0.855, 0.060);
  transform: translate3d(0, -30px, 0);
  }
  70% {
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.755, 0.050, 0.855, 0.060);
  transform: translate3d(0, -15px, 0);
  }
  90% { transform: translate3d(0,-4px,0);
  }
  } 
  @keyframes tada {
  0% {
  transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  }
  10%, 20% {
  transform: scale3d(.9, .9, .9) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -3deg);
  }
  30%, 50%, 70%, 90% {
  transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 3deg);
  }
  40%, 60%, 80% {
  transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -3deg);
  }
  100% {
  transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  }
  } 
<img src="tag-logo.png" class="animited tada bounce">
```

I've tried class="bounce tada" class="animated bounce" class="bounce"
I've seen somewhere about adding in animation-delay: but even adding in animation-delay only delay's the actual bouncing animation.

Would really appreciate it if someone could help me figure this out.
I know its better to use this with jquery, transit but i wouldn't have the first clue where to even begin with the markup code for them both.

Answer (score 1):

you can use animation with delay like this:

```
-webkit-animation: animation-one 1s, animation-two .3s;
-moz-animation: animation-one 1s, animation-two .3s;
animation-delay: 0s, 1s;
```

or transition with delay like this and it will change property one after other.

```
transition: 
  /* step 1 */
  width      1s,
  /* step 2 */
  background 0.5s 1s;
```

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

That's amazing it works @Harel Levy but it now poses another question if you wouldn't mind answering it .

This doesn't work at all

```
animation-name: tada 1s, bounce .3s; 
animation-delay: 0s, 1s;
```

But if you remove **-name** part from the class it works fine? Doesn't it need to be defined with **"animation-name"** as a class in CSS3, not animaton:? I don't get why **animation-name:** stops it working but animation: makes it work. Guessing this is because your method was shorthand right?

Also I cannot get it to work using the method 2 transition could you possibly put an example up like you did above?

I added

`transition: width 1s, background 0.5s 1s; under animation: / animation-name:`

but it's not transforming.